# jQuery DataTable : Delete row and reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

Now, I am working with jQuery DataTable. Everything is going well in intializing data tables with javascript data array.

In my table, it included remove row button. When I clicked the **Remove** button of each row, I delete record using following function.

```
function removeRow(itemList, recordIndex){
    itemList.splice(recordIndex, 1);

    dataTable.clear();
    dataTable.rows.add(itemList);
    dataTable.columns.adjust().draw(false);
}
```

This function performed well with no error. At that, I set **false** to `draw()` function to prevent going to first page when delete records in any other page.This one also working for me.

The problem is, when my `itemList` has **11** records, and I go to **second page of data table and delete the 11th record**.

So, my `itemList` will left only 10 record and My data table should show the **first** page of paging.

But, jQuery data table is not doing that. It still have in **second page** with **no records**.

I don't know how to fix that one. I want to show previous page after delete every records from current page.

I know **`draw()``** function without **false** parameter will go to first page. But it go to first page in every deletion.

**I only want to go to previous page, when I deleted all records from current page.**

Please, help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found an *hacky way* to get the previous pagination when the current has been emptied.
It is specific to **jQuery DataTable**, since using it's class naming.

Try it in [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/full/amgVqZ/).

```
function removeRow(recordIndex){

    // Get previous pagination number
    var previousPagination= parseInt( $(document).find(".paginate_button.current").data("dt-idx") ) -1;

    // Splice the data.
    data.splice(recordIndex,1);
    myTable.clear();
    myTable.rows.add(data);
    myTable.columns.adjust().draw(false);   // May ajust the pagination as empty... `.draw(false)` is needed.

    // Decide to redraw or not based on the presence of `.deleteBtn` elements.
    var doIdraw=false;
    if($(document).find(".deleteBtn").length==0){
        doIdraw=true;
    }
    myTable.columns.adjust().draw(doIdraw); // Re-draw the whole dataTable to pagination 1

    // If the page redraws and a previous pagination existed (except the first)
    if(previousPagination>1 && doIdraw){
        var previousPage = $(document).find("[data-dt-idx='" + previousPagination + "']").click();
    }

    // Just to debug... Console.log the fact that only one pagination is left. You can remove that.
    if(previousPagination==0 && doIdraw){
    }
}
```

**Notice** that I used:

- `#myTable` as the table `id`
- `.deleteBtn` as the delete buttons `class`
- `data` as the dataTable data

I removed all `console.log()` and example related code in the code above (but not in CodePen).

***"Delete this →"* button handler** is:

```
$("#myTable").on("click",".deleteBtn",function(){

    var rowElement = $(this).closest("tr");
    var rowIndex = myTable.row(rowElement).index();
    removeRow(rowIndex);
});
```